# Prevent auto Line Break in Multi lines TextView

Tags: android, textview

I know this question has been ask several times but maybe not exactly for this requirement.

I want to create a log view, so currently based on a `TextView` and obviously, like in all log views, in AS's logcat for example, I will have several lines so I can enable `vertical scrollbar` and I can have long log lines, each line terminated by a `\n`.
Here I hoped that `horizontal scrollbar` could help me. But it seems not, right?

If not, how to do?

**EDIT** my current Textview definition:

```
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvLog"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:inputType="none"
                    android:lines="5"
                    android:maxLines="20"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/elvTests" />
```

Answer (score 0):

as i have understood that you want all text to be displayed and that you can scroll it downwards so based on that i guess you can do something like this

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/long_text"/>
</ScrollView>
```

putting your text view in a scroll view that matches its parent  in width and height and a text view with wrap_content will enable this behavior hope this helps

**EDIT**

put this in your code that should do the work

```
TextView textview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);
textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm expecting for. I've updated my question to give my current TextView definition. with `maxLines` and `vertical` scrollbar; I don't need a scrollview and I can scroll the textView vertically. but a long text line is wrapped out into multi lines and this is I don't want.